# Bootstrap labels inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <label></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <!-- ko if: count -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" data-bind="text: count"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: error -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="text: error"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
  <label data-bind="text: fromdate"></label>
  <label data-bind="text: todate"></label>
</div>
```

How can I make labels for the `fromdate` and `todate` inline with the input-group? They are coming from ajax call but i still seem to not be able to inline them. Changed the column size and still nothing.

I cannot use `form` because the masterpage has `form` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your div an id like "custom-col" etc.
then in your css

```
#custom-col > label,
#custom-col > div.input-group{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

will do the trick